# Bernoulli event expansion in 0 to 3 occurrences cancel to first order

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am working through Hamming's *The Art of Probability* and am having trouble with a problem in the Bernouilli Trials section. The wording is the following

> Expand the binomials in the probabilities of 0, 1, 2, and 3 occurrences, and show that the expansions cancel out to the next term provided $np \lt 1$. Hence if $np \ll 1$, the first term neglected in the expansion is close to the exact result for 4 or more events.

I am assuming that the solution should give something like $\sum_{k = 0}^{3}B(k; n, p) = np + \mathcal{O}\left [(np)^4 \right ]$ but I can't actually get anything that cancels to the first order.

Using the recursion relation of Bernouilli trials, $B(k+1; n, p) = \frac{n - k}{k+1}\frac{p}{q}B(k; n,p)$, I get

$$(1 - p)^n \left (1 + \frac{np}{q} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{p^2}{q^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}\frac{p^3}{q^3} \right)$$

Expanding this and keeping the terms 0th and first order in $np$ yields

$$(1-p)^n \left (1 - \frac{1}{6}\frac{6 p^3 -29 p^2 + 33 p - 12}{(1-p)^3} + \mathcal{O}\left [(np)^2 \right ]\right )$$

Am I misunderstanding the question? I expected the second term to cancel.

**Edit:** I guess one could use the expansion for $\exp (-np) \approx \left ((1-p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \right )^{-np}$ and then expand it in a Taylor series, $\exp (-np) = 1 - np + \frac{(np)^2}{2} - \frac{(np)^3}{6} + \mathcal{O}\left [(np)^4\right ]$. This matches the terms of the form $(np)^k$ and they do have the opposite signs, but I don't quite understand why you can get away with ignoring the $q$ in the denominator. That is,

$$\begin{eqnarray}
& \exp (-np) + \frac{np}{q} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{p^2}{q^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}\frac{p^3}{q^3} \\ 
\approx & 1 - np + \frac{(np)^2}{2} - \frac{(np)^3}{6} + \frac{np}{q} + \frac{n^2p^2}{2q^2} + \frac{n^3p^3}{6q^3} + \mathcal{O}\left [(np)^4\right ]\\
\approx &1 + \mathcal{O}\left [(np)^4\right ] ?
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you may be over complicating and what you may need to do is look at the expansion of the expression of the probabilities $$1-\left({n \choose 0}(1-p)^n + {n \choose 1}p(1-p)^{n-1} +{n \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2} + {n \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}  \right)$$ which, by looking at terms up to $p^5$ and simplifying, seems to start $${n \choose 4}{p}^{4}-4{n \choose 5}{p}^{5}+\cdots$$ and then claim that for $np \ll 1$ this is close to  ${n \choose 4}p^4(1-p)^{n-4}$ whose expansion starts ${n \choose 4}{p}^{4}-5{n \choose 5}{p}^{5}+\cdots .$

Not that if you take the difference between these you get ${n \choose 5}{p}^{5}+\cdots $, i.e. close to exact result for $5$ events, and so the pattern continues.